# system load monitor as default view in console

Tags: software-recommendation, system-monitor

Is there a way to have any system load monitor program (say for example, `htop` or `top`) as a permanent view after a server boots up automatically. I am talking about console `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F2` mode.

Of course I could login and type `htop` or `top` but anyone could later  `q`  and get a login shell.

Therefore, I need it to autologin and display it. Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: You could add a special user, say `observer`, and set `/usr/bin/htop` as that user's login "shell". When that user logs in, `htop` is executed. If he quits it, he is logged off.

Comment: Related (over on U&L) [Start a process on a different tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170063/251553), especially [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170247/251553). Basically: `openvt /usr/bin/top`. This will run `top` on the first free tty.